# Convert a string to an array of strings in c#

Tags: c#, regex, string, linq

Can I get an array of string with CRLF or LF or CR included, only with linq ?
I don't want to use a loop .
I have a string like this  `"Hello \r\n Stackverflow\n How are you doing \r"`, and i have to convert it to be like this

```
mystring[0] = "Hello \r\n"
mystring[1] = "Stackverflow\n"
mystring[2] = "How are you doing \r"
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: `Regex.Split` is probably the easiest here -- `string.Split` will remove the line break characters

Comment: @canton7 show me how to do it plz

Comment: "I don´t want" is usually a really bad reason to do something. Apart from this LINQ **is** looping under the hood.

Comment: @HimBromBeere but it is generally great fun to do such operation with immutable data in Aggregate... (need to remember previous character for "\r\n" vs. "\r" distinction definitely calls for fun code).

Comment: In your example, you are also removing spaces at the start and end of the substrings. Is this intended?

Comment: @MatthewWatson no

Comment: `Regex.Split(s, @"(?<=\r\n)|(?<=\n)|(?<=\r)")` [almost gets you there](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SQbvk4), but it splits the `\r\n` into two separate lines for reasons that I don't understand

Answer (score 1):

This is slightly complicated by the fact that we have to handle "\r", "\n" AND "\r\n". I'm assuming you don't need to handle "\n\r" - if you do, you'll have to add a case for it in the code below.

Obviously there are many ways to solve this; here's a low-level approach that doesn't use anything other than a basic loop:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SplitByAndKeepLineSeparators(string input)
{
    if (input.Length == 0)
        yield break;

    int i = 0, j = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        if (i == input.Length - 1) // Last char?
        {
            yield return input.Substring(j, i - j + 1);
            break;
        }

        switch (input[i])
        {
            case '\r' when input[i+1] == '\n':
                yield return input.Substring(j, i - j + 2);
                i += 2;
                j =  i;
                break;

            case '\r':
                yield return input.Substring(j, i - j + 1);
                j = ++i;
                break;

            case '\n':
                yield return input.Substring(j, i - j + 1);
                j = ++i;
                break;

            default:
                ++i;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: If using an older version of C# you won't be able to use that kind of `switch`, so your code would have to be:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SplitByAndKeepLineSeparators(string input)
{
    if (input.Length == 0)
        yield break;

    int i = 0, j = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        if (i == input.Length - 1) // Last char?
        {
            yield return input.Substring(j, i - j + 1);
            break;
        }

        if (input[i] == '\r' && input[i + 1] == '\n')
        {
            yield return input.Substring(j, i - j + 2);
            i += 2;
            j =  i;
        }
        else if (input[i] == '\r')
        {
            yield return input.Substring(j, i - j + 1);
            j = ++i;
        }
        else if (input[i] == '\n')
        {
            yield return input.Substring(j, i - j + 1);
            j = ++i;
        }
        else
        {
            ++i;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try the below line please:-

```
var arr = mystring.Split('\n');
```

Comment: what about \r  ?

Comment: i will not get what i need

Comment: Split can accept param array, you can pass multiple comma separated chars in split function.

Comment: Split() doesn't include the splitter characters in the returned strings.